# Cross-domain jQuery AJAX POST redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, cross-domain, http-status-code-302

I'm very new to this field and I was fiddling with my school's homework system to see if I could request and parse the data myself (not trying to break into the system).

So when a student enters an username and password, the form use the POST method. However, this doesn't directly return the html with the hw, instead does a 302 redirect to a GET url, which returns the content I actually want.

Obviously this presents the problem of cross-domain requests and I don't have control over the server side, so I can't do CORS. I also looked into YQL, but that only seems to support GET.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, don't use your browser to do this.

Comment: What server-side language is available to you? ASP, PHP, RUBY, PYTHON, PERL?

Comment: I believe it is asp. Oh, so if I don't use a browser, how can I do it?